# WPF Navigation control

Tags: wpf, navigation

I need back/next buttons with dropdown history (like in Internet Explorer).

The thing is, I need this in a UserControl and to databind the history to an IObservableCollection.  I have my own class for navigating, I just need the navigation control.

Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1):

In your Navigation UserControl you can have a ContentControl/ContenPresenter to which you can set one of your ViewModel instances at a time from the ObservableCollection.
Provided you have defined proper DataTemplates globally, so that when you set the Content WPF will take the appropriate DataTemplate to display the View.